# unable to parse Procfile

Tags: heroku, foreman, procfile

I am trying to deploy an Heroku app.

I must be doing something wrong with the Procfile. When I run `foreman check` I get this error.

> ERROR: no processes defined

I get pretty much the same thing when deploying on Heroku

```
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types

 !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
```

The Procfile looks like this

> web: node app.js

What did I miss?

---

**update** I re-did all from the start, It works properly now. I think I might have issue with Unix line ending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `Procfile` in the root of your project? Is it spelled with a capital P? Does it have unix line endings?

Comment: Yes it's in the root. it's correctly spelled, and git track the correct spelling. I think I will got with the unix line endings because I am on windows.

Answer (score 19):

Just encounter "Push failed: cannot parse Procfile." on Windows.
I can conclude that 
It IS "Windows-file format" problem, NOT the context of file itself.

make sure to create a clean file, maybe use Notepad++ or other advanced editor to check the file type.

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure this out. I re-created the file in Notepad++ and that solved the issue!

Answer (score 10):

save as a utf-8 character file, rather than what it is - a utf 16 character file. this is a confirmed fix.

Comment: this one was the one helping me, the other top comment didn''t explain what kind of file character should we used

Answer (score 8):

Open your current Procfile with notepad. Create a new Procfile.txt and paste the content of your original Procfile . Save your Procfile and replace it with your new Procfile

Comment: This fixed it for me on Windows 10  PowerShell

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, using VSCode I changed file to UTF-8 (bottom right), saved file and pushed it - and it was successful.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening due to a **different encoding type** in your **Procfile**.

1. Open your Procfile in a text editor, preferably, **Notepad**.
2. Save the file and in the encoding option, change the encoding to **UTF-8** (default is UTF-16).
3. Replace your current Procfile with this file in the root folder of your project and remove the .txt extension.

Push your code again and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Create `Procfile` using the following command,

```
echo web: gunicorn app:app > Procfile
```